# for-loop with multiple variable declarations

Tags: java, groovy

I'm pretty sure the following is legal in Java

```
for (int var1 = 2, var2 = 3; var1 < 10; ++var1) {
  System.out.println(var1);
}
```

But when I try to run it in the Groovy console, I get this error

> unexpected token: =

Are multiple variable declarations unsupported by Groovy or is there another reason why this isn't allowed?

Comment: Definitely legal in java.

Comment: It must be some issue with Groovy. The same code segment works fine in Java. I'm not too familiar with Groovy myself, but I found the following via a quick google search, and it may help you out: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/multiple-variable-assignment-in-groovy/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a common gotcha for Java Developers.  See this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-grails/9781449324513/ch01.html) for more detail:

Common gotchas
**you can use only one count variable**.

Excerpts from the link:

> **for Loops**
>
> Another small difference is that you can’t initialize more than one variable in the first part of a for loop, so this is invalid:
>
> ```
> for (int count = someCalculation(), i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> and you’ll need to initialize the count variable outside the loop (*a rare case where Groovy is more verbose than Java!*):
>
> ```
> int count = someCalculation()
> for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> or you could just skip the whole for loop and use times:
>
> ```
> someCalculation().times {
>    ...
> }
> ```

Comment: ... Maybe a link would be better until the cut-and-paste does what you want.