# Groovy. Multiple initialization in "for" loop doesn't compile

Tags: java, groovy

When I executed the following code using the built-in Groovy tool in IntelliJ IDEA, an error occurred.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()

String a = "abc"

String b = "123"


for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length() || j < b.length(); i++, j++) {


    if (i < a.size()) {
        print(a[i])

        sb.append(a[i])
    }

}

print(sb)
```

Error is as follows

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 8: unexpected token: = @ line 8, column 12.
   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length() || j < b.length(); i++, j++) {
              ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
```

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length() || j < b.length(); i++, j++) {
```

My guess is that the grammar problems, but didn't send any questions。

Comment: "I use the idea of groovy code execution，why?" this subject doesn't make sense. Please update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Groovy do you use? At some point Groovy didn't support initialization of more than one variable in the first part of a `for` loop. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386418/1842599

I've checked with Groovy 4 (I have `4.0.8` installed), multiple initialization works like a charm.

So, you may consider upgrading your Groovy version or rewrite your code, if upgrade is not possible.

Comment: It is highly likely that the issue is related to the Groovy version. My Groovy version is 2.4.5.

Comment: @Daniel then it's 100% it. Groovy 2 doesn't support it. Install Groovy 4 and check, it should work.

Comment: I upgraded the groovy version to 4.0.7  it woks  now . I can't vote for i am  a novice, appreciate your reply @Andrej Istomin

Comment: @Daniel Even if you cannot vote, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin  yes  i  accepted.